# Exclude CorePartsFeedItemBuilder in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I am creating a custom IFeedItemBuilder in my Orchard module and it is working as I expect.  The problem, though, is that I want to set the value of the description element for items on my feed.  I am able to do this, but what I set gets overwritten by another IFeedItemBuilder in the pipeline: CorePartsFeedItemBuilder.  Is there a recommended way to opt out of this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorate your implementation of IFeedItemBuilder with the `OrchardSuppressDependency` as so:

```cs
[OrchardSuppressDependency("Orchard.Core.Feeds.StandardBuilders.CorePartsFeedItemBuilder")]
public class MyFeedItemBuilder : IFeedItemBuilder {
   /* class body */
}
```

This, as excepted, suppresses the dependency and makes `MyFeedItemBuilder` **THE CHOSEN ONE** :)

Have a look at RegisTagCache.cs in the Orchard.Redis module.
For a better understanding have a look at this blog post by Roland: [Using the OrchardSuppressDependency Attribute](http://rolandthompson.co.uk/blog/orchard---using-the-orchardsuppressdependency-attribute)

Comment: Exactly what I sought - thank you for pointing out this easy answer.